# How to have the same SlidingUpPanel for all activities

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, drawerlayout, slidingdrawer

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
        xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        sothree:umanoPanelHeight="68dp"
        sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp"
        sothree:umanoParallaxOffset="100dp"
        sothree:umanoDragView="@+id/dragView"
        sothree:umanoOverlay="true"
        sothree:umanoScrollableView="@+id/main">

        <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                sothree:theme="@style/ActionBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"


            />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <!-- SLIDING LAYOUT -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:id="@+id/dragView">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="68dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/panel">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="68dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="0.8">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/footer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/foooter"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="68dp"
                android:layout_height="68dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/playy"
                android:id="@+id/play"
                android:background="@null"
                />
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="68dp"
                android:layout_height="68dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/queue"
                android:id="@+id/queue"
                android:background="@null"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/ss"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                >

              <!--  <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/list_main"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Main Content"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />-->

                    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/panel">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/songThumbnail"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"
                            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_weight="0.9"
                            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                           >

                            <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:id="@+id/album_art"
                                android:src="@mipmap/music"
                                />
                        </LinearLayout>


                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            >

                            <SeekBar
                                android:id="@+id/songProgressBar"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"

                                android:thumb="@mipmap/seek_handler"
                                                      android:progressDrawable="@mipmap/img_seekbar_bg"
                                android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                                android:paddingRight="6dp"/>

                            <!-- Timer Display -->
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/timerDisplay"
                                android:layout_above="@id/songProgressBar"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
                                <!-- Current Duration Label -->
                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/songCurrentDurationLabel"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:gravity="left"
                                    android:textColor="#eeeeee"
                                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
                                <!-- Total Duration Label -->
                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/songTotalDurationLabel"
                                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:gravity="right"
                                    android:textColor="#04cbde"
                                    android:textStyle="bold"/>


                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="200dp"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_weight="0.1"
                            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                            >


                            <!-- Previous Button -->
                            <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/bt_previous"
                                android:src="@mipmap/previous"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:background="@null"
                                android:layout_weight="2"
                                />

                            <!-- Backward Button -->

                            <!-- Play Button -->
                            <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/bt_play"
                                android:src="@mipmap/playy"
                                android:layout_width="100px"
                                android:layout_height="100px"
                                android:background="@null"
                                android:layout_weight="2"/>
                            <!-- Forward Button -->

                            <!-- Next Button -->
                            <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/bt_next"
                                android:src="@mipmap/next"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:background="@null"
                                android:layout_weight="2"
                                />


                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

            </FrameLayout>



        </LinearLayout>
    </com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>






</RelativeLayout>
```

The above is my XML code for SlidingUpPanel, which is used in my Main Activity.It has two parts, main content (the normal screen) and the sliding content (which will come from bottom of the screen).Now the problem is this panel will only be displayed in the Main activity.I want to display the panel for all my activities.Guide me how to go about.

Please Help
Thanks..!!

Comment: Have the sliding panel in a Fragment and add the fragment whenever you need it in an Activity (https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html)

Comment: I suggest you to put whole SlidingPanel xml in a layout file and call it in every activity. Of course using fragments is tough but more convienced.

Answer (score 0):

well if you want same slidingmenu with same content in all your activities then simply create an Activity and code the logic of sliding menu there say its name to be `BaseActivity` then extend this `BaseActivity` in all other activites of your project instead of `AppCompatActivity`, so you will get it available in all activities.

Another approach would be a `Fragment` containing SlidingMenu as suggested in comments by @Veeresh , that is also a good option available for you

Answering your comment make a variable in your MainActivity like this

```
 public  SlidingUpPanelLayout ss; // this is important step , did you followed this in your mainactivity
```

its the class variable then inside `onCreate` method

```
ss=(SlidingUpPanelLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_layout);
```

then in other activities you can get it directly by `ss`

Comment: do i need to have same kind of xml layouts for for all activities,or only one xml layout is enough for all the activies?

Comment: no, only one layout contains sliding menu which is BaseActivity

Comment: MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity,and SecondActivity extends MainActivity.............is this correct?

Comment: i have defined my slidinguppanel as SlidingUpPanelLayout ss =(SlidingUpPanelLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_layout); in MainActivity, do i need to create an object of MainActivity in my SecondActivity to access  slidinguppanel

Comment: accept my answer then, by clicking on green check just below the upvote button in my answers's top left corner

Comment: R.id.sliding_layout is in my activity_main's layout and not activity_second layout..thats y it is not showing ,but the action bar settings button is getting imported

Comment: you don't need to use findViewById in other activities except the main activity, for getting reference to slidingmenu, may simply use ss for it

Comment: my second activity also has a layout,thats y i guess

Comment: what not worked are you not getting reference to ss in other activities extending the MainActivity

Comment: yea i m getting the referenced,but see my code above,i dont have a seperate sliding up panel xml,its included in my activity_main

Comment: that fine don't place anyother content in your main activity, as I told you in the very beginning of my answer make a seperate activity and include the code of  slidingmenu and then extend this activity in other activities , did you followed me correctly?

Comment: yes the problem is solved, but now the problem is whatever changes i m making to ss (object of SlidingPanel) in the first screen doesn't reflect in the other screen.

Comment: that is obvious because the code is same everywhere

Answer (score 0):

Create your sliding content in a separate layout and inflate it in your any activity

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);


        View inflatedLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout1, null, false);
        inflatedLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
```